# Why do I get a FROM Clause Error when trying to join an aliased Subquery?

Tags: postgresql

I get the error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "Events"
> LINE 6:  "Events"."EventCount"

from running this query.

```
SELECT 
    "Devices"."DeviceId",
    "Devices"."DisplayName",
    "Devices"."CreatedDateUtc",
    "Devices"."ModifiedDateUtc",
    "Events"."EventCount"
FROM "Devices"
JOIN(
    SELECT "DeviceEvents"."DeviceModelId", COUNT("DeviceEvents"."Id") AS EventCount
    FROM "DeviceEvents"
    WHERE "DeviceEvents"."CreatedDateUtc" > '9-1-2020'
    AND "DeviceEvents"."CreatedDateUtc" < '10-1-2020'
    GROUP BY "DeviceEvents"."DeviceModelId"
    ) AS Events 
ON "Devices"."Id" = "Events"."DeviceModelId"
```

At first I thought it was because I was calling the alias before it was created, so I did this:

```
SELECT "Devices"."DeviceId",
    "Devices"."DisplayName",
    "Devices"."CreatedDateUtc",
    "Devices"."ModifiedDateUtc",
    "Events"."EventCount"
FROM(
    SELECT "DeviceEvents"."DeviceModelId", COUNT("DeviceEvents"."Id") AS EventCount
    FROM "DeviceEvents"
    WHERE "DeviceEvents"."CreatedDateUtc" > '9-1-2020'
    AND "DeviceEvents"."CreatedDateUtc" < '10-1-2020'
    GROUP BY "DeviceEvents"."DeviceModelId"
    ) AS Events
JOIN "Devices" ON "Devices"."Id" = "Events"."DeviceModelId"
```

But it just gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quote Events join alias:

```
SELECT 
    "Devices"."DeviceId",
    "Devices"."DisplayName",
    "Devices"."CreatedDateUtc",
    "Devices"."ModifiedDateUtc",
    "Events"."EventCount"
FROM "Devices"
JOIN(
    SELECT "DeviceEvents"."DeviceModelId", COUNT("DeviceEvents"."Id") AS EventCount
    FROM "DeviceEvents"
    WHERE "DeviceEvents"."CreatedDateUtc" > '9-1-2020'
    AND "DeviceEvents"."CreatedDateUtc" < '10-1-2020'
    GROUP BY "DeviceEvents"."DeviceModelId"
    ) AS "Events"
ON "Devices"."Id" = "Events"."DeviceModelId"
```

Comment: Also noticed that the subquery stripped the capitalization.  Had to change "Events"."EventCount" to "Events"."eventcount".

Comment: Personally it's safer to avoid double quoted table names :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT 
    "Devices"."DeviceId",
    "Devices"."DisplayName",
    "Devices"."CreatedDateUtc",
    "Devices"."ModifiedDateUtc",
    "Events"."EventCount",
    "DeviceEvents"."DeviceModelId",
    COUNT("DeviceEvents"."Id") AS EventCount
GROUP BY "DeviceEvents"."DeviceModelId" AS "Events"
FROM "Devices"
JOIN "DeviceEvents"
ON "Devices"."Id" = "Events"."DeviceModelId"
WHERE "DeviceEvents"."CreatedDateUtc" > '9-1-2020'
AND "DeviceEvents"."CreatedDateUtc" < '10-1-2020'
```